# Is there a way to call a module via its path or something?

Tags: erlang

I have a mock module where I'd like to pass through certain function calls to the original, but the mock module hides the original. Can I call the original by path somehow, or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Meck](http://eproxus.github.com/meck/), a mocking library for Erlang, to achieve this:

> With meck you can easily mock modules
>   in Erlang. Since meck is intended to
>   be used in testing, you can also
>   perform some basic validations on the
>   mocked modules, such as making sure no
>   function is called in a way it should
>   not.
>
> meck automatically renames existing
>   modules in case they are loaded when
>   you want to mock them, and restores
>   them upon unloading of the mocked
>   module. It is also possible to call
>   the original functions from a mocked
>   module using `meck:passthrough/1` from
>   inside an expectation.